# Avoid text clipping of symbols in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have defined some symbols with text properties to act as a label for some other symbols. With the text-halo property I tried to make a background for the text. However, when zoomed out, the text starts clipping and becomes quite unreadable. Example below:

[image]

The layout of these four symbols is defined as follows:

```
'text-font': ['Open Sans Regular'],
'text-field': '{metadata}',
'symbol-placement': 'point',
'text-size': 20,
'text-allow-overlap': true,
'text-offset': [0, -2],
'text-anchor': 'top'
```

And the paint property of the symbols:

```
'text-halo-color': '#fff',
'text-halo-width': 5
```

I want the label on top covering the others completely, like the behaviour of a z-index in CSS. Any ideas? I already tried a dozen combinations of all the possible property values but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, all halos are drawn first, then text. So a halo will never cover the text of another layer. This behaviour is intentional, and has been discussed [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4709).

The obvious workaround would be to not use `text-allow-overlap`, and find some other solution to whatever problem you were trying to solve using that.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible for the symbols to rearrange themselves so they don't collide anymore in a straightforward manner? That way all labels are visible and readable.